# Question based on cost price, market price and discount

Tags: algebra-precalculus

One merchant correctly calculates his profit percentage on the cost price; another wrongly calculates it on the selling price. Find the difference in the actual profits if both claims to make 30% profit, and their revenue is 3900.

Correct profit percentage is 
$P/C.P*100=30$

Wrongly calculated profit
$P/S.P*100=30$
$P/3900*100=30$ which gave me $1170$

How to calculate profit from correct profit percentage? Also, let me know if I am doing it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

The profit in the first case is $P_1=\frac{3900-C_1}{C_1}=0.3$

And the profit in the second case $P_2=\frac{3900-C_2}{3900}=0.3$

Comment: Thanks @callculus

Comment: You´re welcome.

Comment: You can accept the answer if you want.

Comment: Didn't get what you saying?@callculus